# Installation interrupted by power off, now get GRUB command line and cannot boot

Tags: grub2, gnu

My laptop turned off while finishing Ubuntu installation and now all I get is a GRUB command line.

I don't know what to do. I want to boot my usb but every command I try does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Use the BIOS boot menu to boot from the USB. To enter the BIOS boot menu, you have to press a key as the computer turns on. This varies by manufacurer, look at the screen when the computer turns on, it might say which key to press to enter boot menu. Otherwise, look up your computer and how to enter BIOS boot menu.

Once you enter the boot menu, select the USB drive and try the installation again.